# Main SASS file to multiple CSS files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gruntjs

So I have this unusual situation, may be it's not Sassy way OR the right way and that's why I am asking it.

I have a main.scss which basically imports all other partials and frameworks say bootstrap. It works perfectly if all I needed was one single global CSS but I require different css files for various components and pages. One option could have been to include variables and mixins in every SASS file and compile different SASS files. Following are the reasons I didn't venture this path-

1. This somehow doesn't seem right, may be there is much efficient and automated way.
2. Not everything is coded by me or I may not have options to arrange variables and mixins locations. E.g. variables and mixins are not declared in separate files and I might not have option to re-factor.

One option which I am using is to split final compiled css using grunt and placing them in different folders but then changing images and font path is turning out to be a big trouble. I am not sure how do I use imgmin or such utilities to solve my problem neither that I am using the most efficient way to achieve what I want. I also want to avoid much complications in workflow.

Looking for some advice or tip which may help me out.

Comment: looks like your workflow is very wrong, you don't need to change sass behavior, but your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would say that compiling multiple SASS files doesn't seem right.  That's how I'd approach it.

If you have a lot of variables and mixins, put the shared ones into a single file.

**_shared.scsc:**

```
$blue: #3b97c6;
$grey: #e6e6e6;

@mixin my_mixin {
  // ...
}
```

Then just have your multiple SASS files (without the underscore so that they get compiled individually).

**sass1.scss**

```
@import "_shared";

// stuff only for sass-1
```

**sass2.scss**

```
@import "_shared";

// stuff only for sass-2
```

**sass3.scss**

```
@import "_shared";

// stuff only for sass-3
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Hi @manishie , my "Not feeling right" comment was not for compiling multiple SASS files but for the need to manually importing variables / mixins in every SASS file. Combining all the variables in one file is not possible in my case.